# Positioning images using the margin

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the dumb question, I am totally new to HTML/CSS and need some help.

1 - I am trying to position my 2 image boxes next to each other, I can't seen to move the purple box up as when I add margin it does not recognise.

2- Neither the lime image or purple image recognises when I add margin-top. How can I move these both up or down?

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="WEBSITE_PRODUCTS_SMARTWESTERN.jpg"
  img.resize
  max width="50%"
  max height="50%"
  align="right"
  margin="top" />
</div>
```

Comment: please show your code properly

Comment: have you tried inside a table?

Comment: Tried to edit as much as possible so to have a proper closing tag.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Put image 1 here</h4>
<p><img style="margin: 0 0 5px 20px; float: right;" src="https://htmlg.com/images/demo-image.jpg" alt="Castle" width="155" height="156" /></p>
</td>
<td>
<h4>Put image 2 here</h4>
<p><img style="margin: 0 0 5px 20px; float: right;" src="https://htmlg.com/images/demo-image.jpg" alt="Castle" width="155" height="156" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```